# Disable wavy underline in Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZfgs.png)
I have a problem with my file displaying these wavy underline notifications at the class attributes of my tags. How can I disable this?

Comment: what is it showing when you hover over them?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio Code, those squiggly lines mean a `warning` in your code.
VSCode performs **background code analysis** to provide you feedback about syntax and compilation errors.

In Visual Studio it **usually means a variable is declared and not used**. Or maybe you have copied and pasted code with illegal characters?
Can't you just hover over the attribute and give us more context about the error message?